# Excel VBA - Highlighting pairs of positive and negative numbers

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose I have a column of numbers, for example:

> 1; -1; 5; 4; 3; -3; -3; 3; -4; 7.

I want to make a macro that can highlight all pairs of positive and negative numbers (ex. 1 and -1) while also taking in consideration the fact that multiple pairs can appear (ex. 3 and -3 both appear twice). Also, I want to be able to input the range that I want to work with.

For the above example, all numbers should be highlighted except 5 and 7.

**Here's what I came up with so far**

```
Sub HighlightExercise()

Set myRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Sample", Type:=8)

myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 2

For Each cell In myRange

If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 30 Then Next

Set CValue = Cell.Value

myRange.Select

Set CFind = Selection.Find(What:=CValue.Value * -1, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If CFind.Value = Null Then Next

If CFind.Interior.ColorIndex = 30 Then Next

CFind.Interior.ColorIndex = 30

CValue.Interior.ColorIndex = 30

Next

End Sub
```

In the above example, it says "Compile error, Next without For" yet the For condition is there. I tried with "Next Cell" and "Next iteration" but still nothing. What am I not getting?

Comment: Not so sure I am familiar with the **VBA** syntax of `If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 30 Then Next` ? what is this line suppose to do ? Also `If CFind.Interior.ColorIndex = 30 Then Next` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

> `If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 30 Then Next`

You need to test for the opposite and allow it to run the code if true:

```
If cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> 30 Then
```

Also you use `.Value` in many places that does not allow it:

> `Set CValue = Cell.Value`

Should be:

```
Set CValue = Cell
```

But really that is not needed as `Cell` is already a range.

Don't forget to declare your variables:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim cfind As Range
```

Also in the Find, we want to search from the current cell down so change:

> `After:=ActiveCell`

To

```
After:=cell
```

Avoid using `.Select` just do what you want with the range:

```
Set cfind = myRange.Find...
```

try:

```
Sub HighlightExercise()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim cfind As Range
Set myRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Sample", Type:=8)

myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 2

For Each cell In myRange

    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> 30 Then

        Set cfind = myRange.Find(What:=cell.Value * -1, After:=cell, LookIn:= _
            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cfind Is Nothing Then
            If cfind.Interior.ColorIndex <> 30 Then
                cfind.Interior.ColorIndex = 30
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 30
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

---

[image]